# How can I confirm if the NTP server is working correctly?

Tags: ntp

In a bid to get my ip camera timing to sync up, I setup an Ubuntu server as a NTP server (https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-ntp-server/). I used another pc and tested it as a client and the result is as stated in the article.The port 123/udp and firewall are open. However, the ip cameras still doesn't sync up, it unchecks its NTP checkbox after some minutes.

I am new to this NTP thing. However, if my client computer could get its update from the NTP server, can I conclude that my NTP server is working as intended?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

There are at least a few possibilities that may mean it does not work.

First, there could be a version mismatch. Your server may be running NTP v4 and only accepts requests on that version, but the camera wants v3. Secondly, the camera may want a server with a minimum stratum, but your server is lower. Just running tcpdump -v against port 123 may give you hints. It may also be that your server has not sync'd to an ntp source, in which case, the camera could reject it. These are unlikely though, but then again...

You may be able to run ntpq against the camera to get a bit more info.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think that version mismatch is a possibility. Is there a way to find out the version and minimum stratum of the camera? 

Is "ntpq -p <camera's ip address>" the correct command? It returned the message "ntpq: read: connection refused"

Comment: The camera is a ntp client only, not a server, as seen from the ntpq refusal. Just run the tcpdump command will tell you what is requested and sent back. Another possibility is that your camera only picks up the time once, hence the tick disappearing.